# Too many requests, please try again later. Next JS no backend

Tags: next.js

[image]I need help to solve this issue. I'm new at next js ... and every time I refresh my page i get the error "Too many requests, please try again later". This also happens if I click the button too many times. Any one has any Idea how to solve this. Thanks that will be a great help.

using the boiler plate: [@pankod/next-boilerplate](https://github.com/pankod/next-boilerplate).

```
 function believe(): void {
    router.push('/user/believe');
  }


 <button type="submit" className="btn btn--believe color-white w-100 font-14" onClick={believe}>
  Believe
</button>
```

P.S I'm just a newbie

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the guidelines on asking a question! You need to add code, and error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: your issue sounds like an infinite loop of some sort

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly.. thanks .. try to add more details .. I hope this helps

Comment: Can you please now add the code that you're running on the button click, or page refresh.

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly. Thanks for your time and patience ... The error happens on all of my code ... but I posted an example of my code... If I click that 2 or 3 times it says the error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try change `onClick={believe}` to:
`onClick={() => believe()}`
or
`onClick={() => { believe() }}`